# developing on HTC HD2

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, htc-hd2

How Can I develop on HTC HD2 like which tools & SDK TO access WI-FI and Bluetooth..etc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HD2 uses the older Windows Mobile OS. There are SDKs from Microsoft that allow to program for the OS and phone features using Visual Studio.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb158486.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=20686A1D-97A8-4F80-BC6A-AE010E085A6E&displaylang=en

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb158532.aspx

http://www.htchd2forum.com/

Answer (score 1):

It runs Windows Mobile 6.5, so you'd use Visual Studio 2008.

Bluetooth and WiFi interfaces are exposed via sockets.